# When using WM_GETTEXT in SendMessage, VBA crashes

Tags: excel, vba, winapi

In the code below, I am trying to get a string from a third party application into a variable, but the program crashes when it reaches the `SendMessage` line. Please help.

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowTextLength Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextLengthA" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wCmd As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function IsWindowVisible Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Boolean
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32.dll" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWndParent As Long, ByVal hWndChildAfter As Long, ByVal lpszClass As String, ByVal lpszWindow As String) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As Long,  ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long

Private Const WM_GETTEXT As Integer = &HD
Private Const WM_GETTEXTLENGTH As Integer = &HE    

sub test()

  Dim hWndFind As Long, textbox As Long, main_win as long, s as string
  main_win = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Exenta Solution")
  hWndFind = FindWindowEx(main_win , 0, "WindowsForms10.MDICLIENT.app.0.141b42a_r6_ad1", vbNullString)
  textbox = FindWindowEx(hWndFind, 0 , "WindowsForms10.EDIT.app.0.141b42a_r6_ad1", vbNullString)
  Dim buff As String
  textlen = SendMessage(textbox, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0)
  buff = Space(textlen)
  s = SendMessage(textbox, WM_GETTEXT, textlen, buff) **=========> crashes here**

END SUB
```

Comment: You could try `Dim ret As Long; ret = SendMessage(textbox, WM_GETTEXT, textlen + 1, ByVal buff)` or use `ret = GetWindowText(textbox, textlen + 1, buff)`

Comment: Thanks Drake Wu. Adding ByVal in front of buff in the sendmessage function resolved it.

Comment: All your `Declare` statements are wrong. You have [promised](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63801528/11683) to the compiler that you have put `LongPtr` in all places where it needs to be, instead you slapped `PtrSafe` onto every function to silence the warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `SendMessage` return a `Long` as you delcared, but `s` is a `String` type, According to [`WM_GETTEXT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-gettext):

> The return value is the number of characters copied, not including the
> terminating null character.

So add:

```
Dim ret As Long
```

Then `WM_GETTEXTLENGTH` returns the length of the text in characters, also **not including the terminating null character**.  But the `wParam` of `WM_GETTEXT` must **include space for the terminating null character**.

Finally, you need to pass the `ByVal buff` as the last parameter.
Or just use the `GetWindowText` that you've declared:

```
sub test()

  Dim hWndFind As Long, textbox As Long, main_win as Long, textlen as Long
  main_win = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Exenta Solution")
  hWndFind = FindWindowEx(main_win , 0, "WindowsForms10.MDICLIENT.app.0.141b42a_r6_ad1", vbNullString)
  textbox = FindWindowEx(hWndFind, 0 , "WindowsForms10.EDIT.app.0.141b42a_r6_ad1", vbNullString)
  Dim buff As String
  textlen = SendMessage(textbox, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0)
  buff = Space(textlen)
  Dim ret As Long
  ret = SendMessage(textbox, WM_GETTEXT, textlen + 1, ByVal buff) 
  ret = GetWindowText(textbox, buff, textlen + 1)
END SUB
```

Comment: `SendMessage return a Long` - no, it doesn't. It returns a `LongPtr`, which is what [`LRESULT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types#LRESULT) translates to. All the rest API declarations in the OP's code are wrong too.